# В админке в разделе меток вижу странные символы

Tags: wordpress

в разделе меток создаются откуда-то странные теги вида #f8f8f8, #f5f5f5 и т.д.
[image: скриншот прилагаю]
видно что записей нет, хотя если и указывается от 2 до 5 то переходя по ссылке метки записей не найдено.
что может создавать такие метки вообще?
плагин, тема, откуда начать искать, у кого такое может было?

Comment: Скорее всего, сайт инфицирован. Ставьте плагин безопасности, например, Wordfence, и сканируйте.

Comment: вирусов нет сканируя Wordfence, но он указал только что один плагин сейчас не числиться на wp org и все

Comment: Возможно проблемы с кодировкой на разных "участках" - и сервере и база и сайт.

Comment: склоняюсь на вред темы, или ее кодировке точнее. но как переделать кодировку темы.... вот вопрос